# Box made from multiple columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a data frame with a similar structure to this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  Age = c(10, 12, 19, 20),
  Subtraction = c("no", "no", "yes", "yes"),
  Addition = c("no", "no", "yes", "yes"),
  WritesName = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes")
)
```

and I want to make a figure with multiple horizontal box plots displaying the ages at which these children can accomplish specific tasks. similar to this:
[image: multi box plot of age for skills]

I tried making by writing this code

```
ggplot(multi, aes(x = Age, y = c(`Knows basic addition`, `Knows basic subtraction`, `Reads at least 10 words`))) +
geom_boxplot()
```

However I was told the Y axis has to be either 1 or the length of how many rows are in the data frame. How do I make a single figure with boxplots created from multiple rows?

Comment: In your picture you have 4 `y` values, and in your data you have 4 `x` values, but in your code you have only 3 `y` values. If you have a different number of `x` and `y` values, I don't know what you want to plot, and neither does ggplot. Why have you left off `"Writes Names"`? (And why not put these values in your data frame?)

Comment: What are the differently shaded areas in each bar supposed to represent? Your example data is only enough to plot one bar without subdivisions, showing ages when the ability == `"Yes"`...

Comment: I think you should consider what aspects of the data you are trying to visualise. You don't want a boxplot: those are for showing the distribution of values. Are you trying to show the age range for each task? Or a value for each child? Perhaps points would work better than bars.

Answer (score 1):

I assume (possibly and probably incorrectly) That age is on the the color indicates yes vs. no. Not sure what the third is. You need to `pivot_longer` to get the effect you are looking for.

```r
library(tidyverse)

example <- data.frame(
  Age = c(10, 12, 19, 20),
  Subtraction = c("no", "no", "yes", "yes"),
  Addition = c("no", "no", "yes", "yes"),
  WritesName = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes")
)

example |>
  pivot_longer(-Age) |>
  ggplot(aes(Age, name, color = value, group = name))+
  geom_line(size = 4, show.legend = FALSE)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,20))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("lightblue", "blue"))+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]